# почему StringWriter быстрее StringBuilder

Tags: java

`StringWriter` делегирует запись строк в `StringBuffer`, тот в свою очередь не быстрее (а медленнее) чем `StringBuilder`, т.к. использует синхронизацию.
Но тесты показывают, что на больших данных `StringWriter` быстрее.

Comment: Какие тесты? Ссылку бы хоть дали на эти тесты

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, что это был за тест, но ваше утверждение не верно. Написал по быстрому [тест производительности](https://gist.github.com/izebit/5826aa1063d24837ee8e3ae04234df1d) для однопоточного варианта (т.к. `StringBuilder` некорректно сравнивать в другом). Они показали, примерно, одинаковые числа. Почему 
так? Потому что, `synchronized` если используется в одном потоке, находиться в стадии `thin`, где захват лока и его освобождение практически ничего не стоят.